# How can I create a menu entry for Backbox Tools in KDE Plasma 5

Tags: kde, menu

I've recently installed backbox-tools following the instructions [here](https://www.backbox.org/repository).

Once done, I installed `backbox-menu` as well to implement the `xfce` menu.

I see that the `.desktop` entries are created in: `/usr/share/backbox/applications/` and the `.directory` files are available in: `/usr/share/backbox/desktop-directories/`

I copied the entries from: `/etc/xdg/xdg-backbox/menus/xfce-applications.menu` to: `~/.config/menus/applications-kmenuedit.menu` as advised by a lot of Googling, but I cannot seem to get the backbox entries appearing in the KDE Plasma menu.

Can anyone shed any light on this matter? I feel this should either be easier than it is or I'm being stupid and missing something obvious.

I'm running Kubuntu Ubuntu 15.04